# CSP & SSL inline Javascript & how to reference externally

Tags: javascript, java, security, content-security-policy

I'm trying to wrap my head around CSP(Content Security Policy)
before I add to much "stuff" to my site.
I have added the following code, as per Youtube videos & variuos different Documentation sources but i'm having trouble understanding how to work around certain issues.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
        content=" upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src; 
                  style-src 'self' *.dmca.com *.trustlogo.com 
                             *.revolvermaps.com *.deviantart.com    
                             *.ebay.co.uk *.amazon.com
                   connect-src *ra.revolvermaps.com *.revolvermaps.com      
                                https://www.ra.revolvermaps.com/
                                https://www.revolvermaps.com
                   font-src 'self' *;
                   object-src 'self' ;
                   img-src 'self' ;
                   script-src https:www.ssl.comodo.com;></meta>
```

I have on my website An SSL certificate from Comodo, it has two parts to it which are built in script tags, One is in the head tag & the other at the bottom of the body. 
If CSP is working & doing its job then by default inline scripts are disabled? Comodo recommend having these scripts in the head & the body.
     it is not recommended to use inline-Unsafe. 
This part is fine, I have added a reference into the allowed scripts Attribute & the certificate is loading normally with the green padlock at the top. The part that is not working is the logo that used to link back to there site and show a valid certificate. Its disapeard completely. & having tried every combination or instance of comodo reference i the "img-src" attribute of CSP I am posting here to get your views.

How do I implement both SSL & CSP without breaking one.
Can I;
A) put the comodo Scripts in an external .Js file, & if so how do I reference them in the HTML without using inline js. script tags. 
B) is there another img-src link from comodo that I'm missing?
C) do I need to add them to any other attributes of CSP like child or object that I'm unaware of......

I have tried (*secure.comodo.com -- *.trustlogo.com -- comodo_secure_seal_100x85-transp.png -- https://secure.comodo.com/ -- https://ssl.comodo.com -- https://trustlogo.com/images/new-trustlogos/) & many variations of this.... Support has not been very helpful in this matter saying it is not an SSL issue.

ps. "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js" is in the SCRIPT-SRC and seems to work. 
Places where I have put a double "--" indicates a space
Just to be clear, the SSL script is apparently loading, But the Logo, there link and the Padlock image that usually shows the certificate when hovered is not working/showing   Any help would be greatly appreciated this would make rather a wordy Google search request... & I have looked, in fewer words.

Comment: Ps. revolvermaps is also not working with CSP but I'll figure that one out later.. Possibly add it to the child-src, Object-src or download it maybe

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a few tips but if you have a lot of scripts on your site it's gonna take some time until you get the CSP right.

Add `report-uri` and maybe even `report-to` to your site csp-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri

(I know it says `report-uri` is deprecated but as of writing this no browser supports `report-to`)

You'll need to implement some route on your server to cache this reports or signup to some 3rd party service)

From my experience the report is not a bit hard to make sense of, but once you have it setup it's a lot easier to see when your CSP is blocking something. for now it's probably only going to be stuff you didn't configure properly but after you finished configuring CSP properly it is very important to have know when something was blocked on your site and find out how it got to be injected in the first place.

As with Comdo the js code you mentioning has nothing to do with your site actual ssl it is just comodo advertising themself on your web site. If you still want to have their logo and whatever else in you can move the scripts to an external js file with no issue.

JS best practice recommend putting scripts at the end of the body tag (mostly for performance reasons) there is a small chance that placing the script tag in the end of the body tag might cause it to break but I would try it first and only if it doesn't work for some reason I would have move it to the head of the page

Comment: I think i read somewhere that you can use the report-to to send an email? or direct a log file to somewhere or have I got this mistaken....

Comment: I don't mind comodo advertising on my site I quite like there logo & it makes the site look more proffessional, even if its not at that level..

Comment: @RyanStone Not natively. You need to setup an endpoint on your server to get the csp report. once you get it you can log  it, e-mail  it or do anything else with it.

Comment: @RyanStone Personally I don't like this "secure" logo as they are misleading (I've seen a few online stores using them when they didn't have ssl) Also it means nothing about you site security only that the current connection is private so most infect are misleading users. But I can understand how most laymen users can assume it has value